# Redirect permanently from query string to a specific static page in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

The title of the question explains my problem.
I have some dynamic pages urls that I need to map to static pages.
The relation between the dynamic and static pages is 1-1.
1 dynamic page -> 1 static page.
The static page url is completely different from the dynamic one.

Comment: I try to rewrite this query string
http://www.mysite.it/cerca-qui-e-li/categoria?page=shop.product_details&flypage=flypage_images.tpl&product_id=230&category_id=2&manufacturer_id=25
to this one
http://www.mysite.it/product.php?id_product=157

And actually I tried in many different way...escaping characters that may become source of problems...

P.S: I'm trying to do that on my machine...i.e. I've an up and running apache instance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm really sorry that my first question on StackOverflow was a silly one.
Indeed all my problems were related to a lack of attention in editing the file.
I was editing the wrong one!
I'm really sorry.